# Woocommerce rewrite single product page URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website built using wordpress and woocommerce plugin. 
I want to change the product page urls from

```
https://mywebsite.co.uk/product/shampoo/
```

to

```
https://mywebsite.co.uk/products/shampoo/
```

So basically it is just changing **product** to **products**
How can I do that? And is it safe to do so that it won't break any Woocommerce functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has this functionality built into the permalink system. Once you install Woocommerce, the permalink settings page changes and allows for a custom permalink to be set for the shop side of things.

Here's a good example to follow : https://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-setup-and-manage-shop-permalinks.html

What you're looking to do is use the custom base setting which should be the last option on the permalink page. Good luck! Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the permalink from product to "products". The option was already there. But it didn't work.

Comment: nevermind, I got it fixed. it was another redirect in htaccess file. Thanks for your answer.